# Optimizing DCPU-16 FizzBuzz

Tags: assembly, fizzbuzz, dcpu-16

I tried to implement FizzBuzz in DCPU-16. I use this web emulator: http://mappum.github.com/DCPU-16/ (repository: https://github.com/mappum/DCPU-16).

It stops before the end of the loop. Why?

How can I optimize it?
I'm a high level language programmer who don't know anything about asm. Have you some *basic* resource on this?

More infos on DCPU-16: official specs: http://0x10c.com/doc/dcpu-16.txt - unofficial specs: http://0x10.cc/

The code:

```
; FizzBuzz in DCPU-16

SET Z, 0x8000
SET I, 1


:loop
    JSR print
    ADD I, 1
    IFN I, 100
        SET PC, loop

    BRK


:print
    ADD Z, 1
    SET [Z], 10

    SET A, I
    MOD A, 3
    IFE A, 0
        JSR printFizz

    SET B, I
    MOD B, 5
    IFE B, 0
        JSR printBuzz

    SET C, A
    IFG B, A
        SET C, B
    ADD A, B
    IFG A, C
        JSR printNumber

    SET PC, POP


:printNumber
    SET A, I

    IFG I, 9
        DIV A, 10

    JSR printDigit

    IFG 10, I
        SET PC, POP

    SET A, I
    MOD A, 10

    JSR printDigit
    SET PC, POP

:printDigit
    ADD A, 48
    ADD Z, 1
    SET [Z], A
    SET PC, POP

:printFizz
    ADD Z, 1
    SET [Z], 70
    ADD Z, 1
    SET [Z], 105
    ADD Z, 1
    SET [Z], 122
    ADD Z, 1
    SET [Z], 122
    SET PC, POP

:printBuzz
    ADD Z, 1
    SET [Z], 66
    ADD Z, 1
    SET [Z], 117
    ADD Z, 1
    SET [Z], 122
    ADD Z, 1
    SET [Z], 122
    SET PC, POP
```

Comment: If you want some ideas for optimising a fizzbuzz, here is my C fizzbuzz made as optimal as I can (without using native functions): http://pastie.org/3739291 . Main technique used is loop unrolling.

Comment: What is "optimizing" in the context of DCPU16? Less instructions?

Comment: @lunixbochs, less cycles. Cycles are already well documented.

Comment: Looks like it's going to be a world filled with many 100KHz CPUs. How efficient does FizzBuzz need to be exactly to make it worth sacrificing readability? :D

Comment: Mind if I add this to https://github.com/jtauber/DCPU-16-Examples ?

Comment: James Tauber: add it if you think that's good enough :)

Comment: How do you implement FizzBuzz on a CPU that has no I/O (yet)?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It does have some I/O now, a textual console with base addres 0x8000 is assumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console space on that emulator is only `0x8000 - 0x8180`.

Looks like you're hitting the end of the console, so your output cuts off mid-letter and you end up writing to unrelated memory.

If you look in the debugger: the register I is 0x64 at compeletion, which is 100 in base-10 (so your loop finished).